# Filling QTableWidget with PGSQL select.(PyQT)

Tags: python, pyqt4, psycopg2

I'm learning `PyQT`, and I want to fill an `QTableWidget` with info retrieved from an query to a `Postgres` database.
I'm using `python/psycog2`.
The query from pgsql cli returns:

```
('Miss', 'Jenny')
('Mr  ', 'Andrew')
('Miss', 'Alex')
('Mr  ', 'Adrian')
('Mr  ', 'Simon')
...
```

And here is my python code:(sorry, it's a little messy)

http://pastebin.com/VQQxabFh

---

---

I get a lot of blank cells on y second column...
Need help.

Thanks for reading.

UPDATE:
FIXED:

http://pastebin.com/d2xp5pCs

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer rather than an update to the question?

Comment: If i remember it, these two lines were wrong, inside the loop,on populate function.
    self.updateSignal.emit()
    self.table_widget.setSortingEnabled(True)